# Drop or impute predictor that is missing around 70% of values, but which is known to be highly relevant?

Tags: predictive-models, missing-data, data-imputation, medicine, dependent-variable

Suppose we have a medical dataset and we are interested in predicting blood pressure using the following variables: age, sex, weight, height, volume of circulating blood, cardiac output, parent with high blood pressure (bwhbp).

The last variable bwhbp is either true or false depending on whether a person has at least one parent with high blood pressure.

Now, assume we are missing around 70% of values for this variable in the dataset. If this was just any old variable we could consider dropping this column altogether, but suppose having a parent with high blood pressure strongly predisposes a person to have high blood pressure. Thus, bwhbp is highly relevant for 30% of the dataset.

Is it 'safe' to impute the bwhp in this rows in which it is missing, i.e. impute it for 70% of the dataset? Or should we drop it altogether because we only have 30% coverage of the dataset? What is the best practise in this situation?

Comment: It would help if you were to give some idea of the sample size and missing values for this predictor. Also, there is one additional possibility: estimating the model including the predictor on the remaining 30% of the sample.

Comment: **Why** Do you have so much missing? Missing at random or informative missingness?

Comment: Let me check and I will get back to you. I will edit the information into my original post.